# Does $\alpha \times \dot \alpha(\theta+c)=\alpha \times \dot \alpha(\theta)$ imply $\alpha(\theta+c)=\alpha(\theta)$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, curves, symmetry

Let $\alpha:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^2$ curve  satisfying $|\dot \alpha|=1$, and define $s= \alpha \times \dot \alpha$, where $\times$ denotes the cross-product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. (I think of $\alpha, \dot \alpha$ as lying in the plane $z=0$ inside $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Suppose that $s(\theta)$ is non-constant, has no zeroes, and that
$
s(\theta+c)=s(\theta)
$
holds for every $\theta$, where $c$ is a constant.

Does $\alpha(\theta+c)=\alpha(\theta)$ or $\alpha(\theta+c)=-\alpha(\theta)$ hold for every $\theta$?

(The latter option can happen for instance when $\alpha$ is a non-circular ellipse.)

---

If we would allow $s=\alpha \times \dot \alpha$ to be constant, then the answer would be negative, in general, e.g. when $\alpha$ is a parametrizing a square, centered around the origin. (Clearly if $s$ is constant, then the condition $s(\theta+c)=s(\theta)$ holds trivially, for every $c$.).

Comment: It denotes the cross-product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I edited.

Comment: I don't think so. Suppose that $\alpha$ is a unit-speed parameterization of a noncircular ellipse. Then, $\alpha(-z) = -\alpha(z)$ and $\alpha'(-z) = -\alpha'(z)$ for all $z$, so $s(-z) = s(z)$ but $\alpha(-z) \neq \alpha(z)$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I forgot about the symmetry $v \times w=(-v) \times (-w)$. Since you only made this observation in a comment, and since there were no answers until now, I have allowed myself to modify the question, to exclude these kind of 'immediate' solutions.

Comment: By the way, your "parameterizing a square" example doesn't satisfy your assumptions -- it fails to be $C^2$ (or even differentiable once) at the corners.

Comment: @AsafShachar As Troposphere pointed out in his answer, the counterexample isn't specific to the ellipse and twofold symmetry: We're simply generalizing to $s(z \operatorname{cis} \theta) = s(\theta)$ but $\alpha(z \operatorname{cis} \theta) \neq s(\theta)$ for values $\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{n}$, $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @TravisWillse Thanks, you are right. I missed using the obvious generalization based on the rotational invariance of the cross-product. The real interesting question is whether this 'trivial' source of symmetry, is the only possibility. I have asked a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128317/does-alpha-times-dot-alpha-thetac-alpha-times-dot-alpha-theta-imp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample would be a (sufficiently nontrivial) curve with rotational symmetry of order $>2$ around the origin. More precisely:

Chose any non-constant periodic $\mathcal C^2$ function $g:\mathbb R\to (0,\infty)$ with period $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ for some $n\ge 3$.

Let $\gamma$ be the curve $\theta\mapsto g(\theta)(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

Let $\beta$ be the curve $\theta\mapsto \frac{2\pi}{\mathop{\mathrm{arclength}} \gamma}\gamma(\theta)$ -- that is, $\gamma$ scaled to have total arc length $2\pi$.

Let $\alpha$ be $\beta$ reparameterized by arc length.

Then $\alpha$ satisfies your assumptions with $c=\frac{2\pi}{n}$, but doesn't satisfy $\alpha(\theta+c)=\pm\alpha(\theta)$.

(Here $s$ will not be constant because it differs between the minimums and maximums of $g$, where in both cases $|s|=|\alpha|$).

---

I think that with the various non-triviality requirements in the question, all counterexamples will have essentially this form.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like an interesting suggestion. Can you please elaborate on your computations? I tried to show that $\alpha \times \alpha'(\theta)=\alpha \times \alpha'(\theta+c)$. It seems to me that this requires $(g\circ \phi)^2 \cdot \phi'$ would have period $c$, where $\alpha=\beta \circ \phi$.

Comment: Also, on a second thought, you can take any path $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha(\theta+c)=R\alpha(\theta)$, where $R \in \text{SO}(2)$ is some fixed element.

Comment: @AsafShachar: $(g\circ \phi)^2\cdot \phi'$ does indeed have period $c$. Namely because $\beta$ is has arc length $2\pi$ and is already parameterized by $[0,2\pi]$, and $|\dot\beta|$ has period $c$, so $\phi(\theta+c)+\phi(\theta)+c$.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Your "second thought" is essentially right, except that you need to make sure to satisfy the auxiliary assumptions in the question. Your $R$ needs to have finite (but nontrivial) order in order for the curve to be closed like it should -- and the _angular_ part of $\alpha$ cannot "go backwards" in some part of the curve, because that would correspond to a sign change of $s$, which you have required to be nonzero.

Comment: (The  conclusion of my first comment should be $\phi(\theta+c)=\phi(\theta)+c$ -- but too late to edit).

Comment: Thanks, but I think that I am still missing something: I indeed verified that $|\dot \beta|$ has period $c$; but I don't see why that forces $\phi(\theta+c)=\phi(\theta)+c$. Using $|\dot \alpha|=1$ all I get is $|\dot \beta(\phi(\theta))| |\phi'(\theta)|=1$ for every $\theta$. Can you please elaborate on how do use the periodicity of $|\dot \beta|$ in order to deduce $\phi(\theta+c)=\phi(\theta)+c$.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Since $g$ is periodic, we have that $\gamma(\theta+c)=R\gamma(\theta)$ where $R$ is a rotation by the angle $2\pi/n=c$. So $\gamma$ splits into $n$ repetitions of $\gamma([0,c])$ each rotated by some a multiple of $c$, and when scaled to get $\beta$, these parts each have arc length $c$. So we have $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi(c)=c$, $\phi(2c)=2c$, etc -- and between these fixed points exactly the same corrections are needed to reparameterize by arc length.

Comment: Or more symbolically: $\phi^{-1}$ is the arc length $\phi^{-1}(\theta) = \int_0^\theta |\beta'(\psi)| \,d\psi$. From the fact that $\phi^{-1}(2\pi)=2\pi$ and the periodicity of $\beta'$ we get $\phi^{-1}(\theta+c)=\phi^{-1}(\theta)+c$ -- in other words the graph of $\phi^{-1}$ is invariant under translating by $(c,c)$, but this then holds for $\phi$ too.

Comment: Thank you for all the patience, and nice explanations. I understand everything now. Indeed, I missed using the general rotational invariance of the cross-product. The real interesting question is whether this 'trivial' source of symmetry, is the only possibility. I have asked a follow-up question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128317/does-alpha-times-dot-alpha-thetac-alpha-times-dot-alpha-theta-imp